# Iterating through columns in a dataframe, how do I turn the row values from objects to strings so I can used regular expressions?

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

I have dataframe of 54k+ rows and 31 columns, and the last 10 columns are essays that I want to investigate.

**The aim of the regex expression I want to run is to strip out the punctuation**

Running this for the very first entry works:

```
essay0 = okcupid.essay0.dropna()
essay0 = essay0.astype('string')  # this is the only way I could find to convert to string

essay_master = essay0
#print(essay_master[0].title())
essay_master = re.sub(r'[\.\?\!\,\:\;\(\)\"]', '', essay_master[0])
print(essay_master)
```

BUT trying to create a way of doing it for every row in all the columns is giving me trouble. The below code is the attempt so far.

**The problem is: why did it work in the above code but not in the loop below? How do I convert the objects into strings so the regex will work?**

```
for col in okcupid[['essay0','essay1']]:
    col = okcupid[col] #col is the iterator and so acts as the index for which we are acting upon
    col.dropna(inplace=True) 
    #col = pd.DataFrame(data=col) # dont think this is needed...
    col.astype('string').dtypes
    #col.convert_dtypes(convert_string=True) # doesnt work
    print(col.dtypes) # still an object
    col = col.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'[\.\?\!\,\:\;\(\)\"]', '', col)) # need string not object
    #for i, row in col.iterrows():
     #   lambda x: re.sub(r'[\.\?\!\,\:\;\(\)\"]', '', row) # this runs but doesnt seem to work on the rows...
```

col.dropna worked so I expected col.astype (with and without .dtypes on the end) to work but it didn't
I tried col.convert_dtypes but that didn't work, and many other things but I'm totally stuck!

Comment: While it's absolutely good practice to use `string` dtype instead of `object`, note that you don't _need_ it to use regex or other string methods. You just need the `.str` accessor. See the list of `Series.str` methods: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.capitalize.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use as much native Pandas methods as possible. Most of them take care of `NaN`/`None`/etc. implicitly. And they are way faster than using custom functions with `.apply`. Here you could try the following:

```py
for col in okcupid.filter(regex="essay\d+", axis=1).columns:
    okcupid[col] = okcupid[col].str.replace("[.?!,:;()\"]", "", regex=True)
```

Instead of the the use of `.filter` you could of course also use `for col in ["essay0","essay1"]`. But since you have like 10 essay columns the use of `.filter` might make your code more concise. Instead of `re.sub` you should use `.str.replace`, which is essentially the same but takes care of the `NaN`/`None`s and is faster. As an aside regarding regex: inside the brackets `[]` you don't have to escape anything, except here the `"` since I'm using it as a string delimiter.

If you apply that to the sample dataframe

```py
okcupid = pd.DataFrame({
    "numbers": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "essay0": ["a, b", None, "c:d;e", "f.g!"],
    "essay1": ["a?", "b; c", "(d)", None]
})
```

```
   numbers essay0 essay1
0        1   a, b     a?
1        2   None   b; c
2        3  c:d;e    (d)
3        4   f.g!   None
```

you'll get

```
   numbers essay0 essay1
0        1    a b      a
1        2   None    b c
2        3    cde      d
3        4     fg   None
```

Comment: Excellent tips! I ran the code and it did the entire thing in 2s! I'll need this as there's more to do on the prog and number of items is going to get pretty big! Really appreciate the extra regex tips too. nan values are still in the set - would you expect this? I may drop them out with .dropna if it affects my aim of creating word clouds (unless you have a better idea on that? ) :)

Comment: @DanInco Yes, I'd exepct `NaN`s to still be present: since the columns are stored on the existing dataframe a `.dropna` on the column/series that gets processed before putting it back on the dataframe wouldn't change anything. A `.dropna` on the whole dataframe (before/after processing, maybe on a subset of columns) would remove the _complete_ row, even if the `NaN` is only present in one column: wouldn't that leed to an information loss?

Comment: thanks that's good insight. I may not even need to do it, but if `NaN` values cause issues, I'll create a new DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation of pandas working with text data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html). The dedicated Pandas type for strings is `StringDtype`.

Also, you don't seem to save the `col.astype` in any variable. Try doing `col= col.astype('string')`

Also check the documentation for the [`Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) method and the [`DataFrame.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) method.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to iterate through your column rows with a `for` loop. You can use the `apply` function. You would first need to define a `function` that does the punctuation stripping. To cast values in a column as strings you can use `astype`:

```
def punct_strip(value):
     if value == np.nan:
      # return what you'd like when nan
     else:
       return re.sub(r'[\.\?\!\,\:\;\(\)\"]', '', value)

okcupid['essay0'] = okcupid['essay0'].astype(str) # Cast values into strings
okcupid['essay0'] = okcupid['essay0'].apply(punct_strip)
okcupid['essay1'] = okcupid['essay1'].astype(str) # Cast values into strings    
okcupid['essay1'] = okcupid['essay1'].apply(punct_strip)
```

The apply function sends each row value in the selected column to the function given. If you'd like to read more on apply [here is the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).